# If the longest road is interrupted and therefore reduced, does the player have to surrender the longest road card?

Tags: catan

I am going to split this into players A and B to simplify my question;(placement rules applied)

Player A has a road which is 7 in length and has the Longest Road tile,

Player B has a road which is 5 in length (second longest road),

Player B builds a settlement mid-way along Player A's road resulting in Player A now having two roads - a length of 4 and a length of 3.

Does Player A surrender the Longest Road card as his previous longest road no longer exists? (and as a result Player B obtains this honour)

Also, if (in the above example) Players B and C had a road less than 5, would the Longest Road card return to the bank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Yes. In the rules it states that if the longest road is split, then you re-evaluate who has the longest road. If no-one qualifies (or it is now a tie) it is returned to the bank.

Building a settlement to split someone's longest road is a key tactic in Settlers, which can be prevented by the player building extra roads and/or settlements to protect the vulnerable spots, but that obviously slows down their road building.

Comment: If this action results in a tie -and- the current holder is one of those tied, I'd expect it to remain with the current holder.  This being equivalent to a second player adding a road section to match the length of your existing 'longest road'.  You need to own an unambiguous Longest Road to gain the card.